# Python doesn't find modules

Tags: python-3.x

I've installed Python3 and PyQt5, but i cant run anything because it says Python can't find module:

```
python3 GUI.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/victor/Documentos/Work_Programming/Python/GUI.py", line 10, in <module>
    from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt5'
```

however i've installed correctly PyQt5, if i try to re-install it, it shows me this:

```
Requirement already satisfied: PyQt5 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (5.14.1)
```

How can i make my python find modules?

My Operative System is Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS

Comment: How exactly did you install it?  Have you confirmed that the files are indeed there under `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages`?

Comment: Yes, they are installed in that folder, i did my installation with: sudo apt-get install python3-pyqt5

Answer (score 0):

Try `sudo apt-get install python3-pyqt5`

If it didn't work try:

```
apt-get install python3-venv
python3 -m venv .venv
source .venv/bin/activate
sudo apt-get install python3-pyqt5
```

and re-install all your requirements and it must work

Comment: Thanks for answering so quickly, here is the output:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pyqt5
Leyendo lista de paquetes... Hecho
Creando árbol de dependencias       
Leyendo la información de estado... Hecho
python3-pyqt5 ya está en su versión más reciente (5.14.1+dfsg-3build1).
0 actualizados, 0 nuevos se instalarán, 0 para eliminar y 3 no actualizados.
```

Comment: sorry I don't understand Espanola  I translated your output I think pyqt5 is installed, now try to run your python script and see if its works

Comment: when it says: 
Requirement already satisfied: PyQt5 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (5.14.1). 

Makes me think PyQt5 is already installed, but when im calling PyQt5 it can't find that module: 

python3 GUI.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/victor/Documentos/Work_Programming/Python/GUI.py", line 10, in <module>
    from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt5'

Comment: Make a virtual environment and install your requirements there and re-try if it works I will update the Answer for you

Comment: Alright. i did it, but still says PyQt5 is already installed, but now i can't run files: 

Installing: 
(.venv) victor@victor-desktop:~/Documentos/Work_Programming/Python$ sudo apt-get install python3-pyqt5
python3-pyqt5 ya está en su versión más reciente (5.14.1+dfsg-3build1).
0 actualizados, 0 nuevos se instalarán, 0 para eliminar y 3 no actualizados.

Trying to run: 
(.venv) victor@victor-desktop:~/Documentos/Work_Programming/Python$ python3 GUY.py
python3: can't open file '/home/victor/Documentos/Work_Programming/Python/GUY.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: Check if `GUY.py` is in the directory where you are this error is because python didn't find the file in the directory

Comment: (.venv) victor@victor-desktop:~/Documentos/Work_Programming/Python$ ls
GUI.py  Testing_PyQT5.ui

Yes, i can see the files if i do LS on that folder

Comment: is this issue still showing up `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt5'`

Comment: remember my main issue is: python cant find modules, but if i try to re-install a module it says it is already installed. Yes it still the same because i cant import that module